# queryLocator - Use date variable

Tags: soql, querylocator

First off, I am not sure how to properly refer to this type of SOQL query. I am working on a batch process and this is the step where you build the query.

What I am having trouble with is putting in a variable that represents a date that is 60 days ago. Can someone tell me the proper way of doing this? Every time I try and execute this code I get an error related to the date variable.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        date d1 = system.today()-60;
        string ds1 = d1.format();

        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Account_Benefit__c, Account_ID__c, Employee__c, Employee__r.Latest_Term_or_Audit_Date__c, ' +
            'Grand_Total_Premium__c, Name ' +
            'FROM Employee_Benefit_Summary__c ' +
            'WHERE Employee__r.Account__r.Separated_EE_Auto_Zero_Benefits__c = TRUE ' +
            'AND Employee__r.Latest_Term_or_Audit_Date__c < ' + ds1 +
            'AND Grand_Total_Premium__c != 0'
        );
    }
```

Comment: side note: use inline soql when possiblre. Using a string is inherently risky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Create an instance of `Date`, based on today, then subtract 60 days from that date. `AddDays` is a bit misleading, since you can add a negative number of days to the date.

   ```
   Date.today().addDays(-60);
   ```
2. Use the [`LAST_N_DAYS` date literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). This can be used to select a period of time (via `=`), or a period before or after the given period of days (via `<` or `>`).

   ```
   Latest_Term_or_Audit_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:60
   ```

Personally, I prefer `LAST_N_DAYS`, since you don't have to do any formatting, but you might need that date for something else.

Comment: `LAST_N_DAYS` is definitely preferred with Dynamic SOQL wherever possible. Otherwise, you must use `String.valueOf(someDate)` - string concatenation results in the wrong Date format for SOQL.

Comment: @DavidReed rather than using `String.valueOf(someDate)`, why not just use a bind variable? They work in dynamic SOQL too, and would allow you to add some more interesting logic (if necessary) to arrive at the date value before your query.
`Date someDate = Utils.addBusinessDays(System.today(), -17);
return Database.getQueryLocator('select Id from SomeObj__c where Date__c < :someDate');`

Comment: @JCD Binds are a better solution possible, you're right. It just adds a dependency on the local scope that occasionally isn't workable depending on how you're building/storing the query.

Comment: I believe the notation should be: Latest_Term_or_Audit_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:60 (with an equals) because LAST_N_DAYS signifies a range of values. See the linked documentation on the answer.